# unable to pass JVM args using gradle in Netbeans. Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring framework and am trying to learn it.
Trying to run in Netbeans 11.2. Failed to run in Eclipse.

Cloned the repository for this online Spring Framework course assignment here 
https://github.com/juleswhite/mobile-cloud-asgn2

However, I am unable to get Application.java to run.

Here is a comment in the file.

```
// The app now requires that you pass the location of the keystore and
// the password for your private key that you would like to setup HTTPS
// with. In Eclipse, you can set these options by going to:
//    1. Run->Run Configurations
//    2. Under Java Applications, select your run configuration for this app
//    3. Open the Arguments tab
//    4. In VM Arguments, provide the following information to use the
//       default keystore provided with the sample code:
//
//       -Dkeystore.file=src/main/resources/private/keystore -Dkeystore.pass=changeit
//


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getOrderedBeansOfType(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:367)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:268)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$InitializerListener.doStart(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:784)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getJettyEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:256)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:133)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at org.magnum.mobilecloud.video.Application.main(Application.java:44)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.geDefaultMessageConverters(DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.<init>(DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.AbstractOAuth2SecurityExceptionHandler.<init>(AbstractOAuth2SecurityExceptionHandler.java:42)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler.<init>(OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler.java:32)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.<init>(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:283)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dc10c53d.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:322)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$57f21d00.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$5(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$57f21d00$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5ea3776c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$57f21d00.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 67 common frames omitted
```

My build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

war {
    baseName = 'gs-convert-jar-to-war'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/milestone" }

    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

    compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.4.RELEASE")

    compile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")

    compile("com.google.guava:guava:17.0")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2")
    compile("com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.0")
    compile("com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0")
    compile("com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0")

    compile("commons-io:commons-io:2.4")

    compile("com.github.davidmarquis:fluent-interface-proxy:1.3.0")
    compile(":mobilecloud.handin:1.0.0")
    compile(":video.like.test:1.0.0")
    compile(":autograder.handin:1.0.0")
    compile(":autograder.spec:1.0.0")

    testCompile("junit:junit")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
}

task wrapper2(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '5.0'
    mainClassName = 'org.magnum.mobilecloud.video.Application'
}

run {
    jvmArgs = ["-Dkeystore.file=src/main/resources/private/keystore", "-Dkeystore.pass=changeit"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with gradle but I can tell you the error is caused by the following in the stack trace:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
```

You're missing a runtime dependency. jaxb-api.jar perhaps?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I did a search at the same time for it. please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just now found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) and added to my build.gradle. And it works!

```
compile ("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11")
compile ("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11")
compile ("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11")
compile ("javax.activation:activation:1.1.1")
```

Comment: Maybe you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57880952/getting-the-error-no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-available-in-sprin?noredirect=1